# mxnet scala use one_hot params error

Tags: scala, mxnet, one-hot-encoding

```
object LoadTest1 {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

var b = NDArray.array(Array(1, 2, 3),
    shape = Shape(1, 3))
//var c = b.copy()
val a = NDArray.one_hot(Map("indices" -> NDArray.array(Array(1f, 2f, 3f), shape = Shape(1, 3)),
    "on_value" -> 1,
    "dtype" -> "float16",
    "off_value" -> 0,
    "depth" -> 4
    //                        "out"->c
))(1)(1)
println(a)

println("-----------------------")
}
}
```

> The code runs with an error like this :
>
> ```
>     Exception in thread "main" ml.dmlc.mxnet.MXNetError: Cannot find argument 'indices', Possible Arguments:
>
>     depth : int, required
>         Depth of the one hot dimension.
>     on_value : double, optional, default=1
>         The value assigned to the locations represented by indices.
>     off_value : double, optional, default=0
>         The value assigned to the locations not represented by indices.
>     dtype : {'float16', 'float32', 'float64', 'int32', 'uint8'},optional, default='float32'
>     18/05/28 17:19:19 INFO util.NativeLibraryLoader: Deleting /var/folders/xh/cjnxxqwx05q4rmf3rz5zmt1r0000gn/T/mxnet4026866899089746779/mxnet-scala
>         DType of the output
>     18/05/28 17:19:19 INFO util.NativeLibraryLoader: Deleting /var/folders/xh/cjnxxqwx05q4rmf3rz5zmt1r0000gn/T/mxnet4026866899089746779
>     , in operator one_hot(name="", depth="1", on_value="1", off_value="0", indices="ml.dmlc.mxnet.NDArray@c3b177e",
> ```
>
> dtype="float16")
>             at ml.dmlc.mxnet.Base$.checkCall(Base.scala:131)
>             at ml.dmlc.mxnet.NDArray$.genericNDArrayFunctionInvoke(NDArray.scala:97)
>             at ml.dmlc.mxnet.NDArray$.one_hot(NDArray.scala:33)
>             at LoadTest$.main(LoadTest.scala:22)
>             at LoadTest.main(LoadTest.scala)
>
> ```
> I think I add the "indices".
>
> I am not very familiar with mxnet Scala, so what's wrong with this?
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val aa = NDArray.one_hot(NDArray.array(Array(1,2,3,4),shape = Shape(4)),4,1,0,"int32")
```

I find that it needn't a Map as param.Just like the code it works.